# Spring Security deprecated issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Trying to configure JWT configuration. Seems like JWT is deprecated. How can I use `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt` now?

My code:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
    http.sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    //http.formLogin(withDefaults());
    http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
    http.headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(frameOptionsConfig -> frameOptionsConfig.sameOrigin()));
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    return http.build();
}
```

Also, in Spring Security 6.0, `antMatchers()` as well as other configuration methods for securing requests (namely `mvcMatchers()` and `regexMatchers()`) have been removed from the API.

Comment: Take a look at Danvega example here https://github.com/danvega/jwt
It helped me to understand the new changes a lot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In addition to @schrom answer and more related to the deprecation of `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer#jwt`, Spring Security deprecated the methods that return its own configurer in favor of the ones that return `HttpSecurity`, and deprecated the `.and()` method from the `HttpSecurity`.

For example, `httpBasic()` is deprecated in favor of `httpBasic(Customizer)`. Those deprecations were done to have only one way to configure the security DSL, which is using lambdas. Take a look [at the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html#_use_the_lambda_dsl).

So, for JWT configuration, you'd have to do:

```java
oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
    .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Spring's general advice is to migrate to Spring 5.8 first, and to 6.0 later, to have a smoother transition to the new features.

As stated in [Spring Security 5.8 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html):

> In Spring Security 5.8, the antMatchers, mvcMatchers, and regexMatchers methods were deprecated in favor of new requestMatchers methods

As far as I know `http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)` should still work, it is even mentioned in the [Spring Security 6.0 documentation about JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html):

Usually Spring classes have a great documentation about deprecated methods, i.e. the JavaDoc often is giving hints which class or method to use instead.

Comment: 'jwt()' is deprecated and marked for removal

Answer (score 1):

Just for the Kotlin devs looking in here

```kotlin
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests { auth ->
            auth.requestMatchers("/myendpoint/**").authenticated()
        }
        .oauth2ResourceServer { oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()) }

        return http.build()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this like:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    // Other stuff
                    .oauth2ResourceServer((rs) ->
                            rs.jwt((jwt) ->jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder()))
                    );
            return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
            // return your JWTdecoder
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking to configure the Customizer for the various HTTPSecurity settings, you can take a cue from below:

```
    @Value("${jwksUri}")
    private String jwksUri;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.oauth2ResourceServer( server -> server.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwkSetUri(jwksUri)));

        http.oauth2ResourceServer( server -> server.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.decoder( myDecoder )));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();

    }
```