# Deprecated methods in Spring 6.1.1

Tags: spring, security, cors, csrf

I am trying to implement `SecurityfilterChain` and many methods have been deprecated such as **`cors()`**, **`and()`**, **`authorizeHttpRequests()`** and **`formLogin()`**.
I am lost and I don't know how to fix my code:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/register")
                .permitAll().and().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/users")
                .hasAnyAuthority("USER","ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().and().build();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security deprecated issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76339307/spring-security-deprecated-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/register")
                .permitAll().and().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/users")
                .hasAnyAuthority("USER","ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().and().build();
    }
```

you can now use:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/register")
                        .permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/users")
                        .hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN"))
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
```